php, xdebug_start_trace; no file and no errors
I am trying to debug PHP project which works on calling php scripts and CMS backend. Xdebug module is on, no mess with config it is basically only loaded by zend_extension=xdebug.so. I try to use it like that:
$debug_log_file_path = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/upload/xdebug.log"; xdebug_start_trace($debug_log_file_path); file_put_contents( $debug_log_file_path . '.test', date('H:i:s') );
My file $debug_log_file_path . '.test' is written correctly; but there is no trace of x-debug. I checked their docs, it says that they use 'relative' path to current working directory. So I also ran this task while being in directory in which it is supposed to be written, in that case it is mounted directory located on another server, I don't know if it matters. Why there is still no x-debug log file? What do I do wrong? I try to get list of called functions and see which one takes the most of the time...

What's the output of that page with xdebug_info() in it?

Hi there, thanks for reply, I found a solution, you have to set xdebug.mode to trace in your config, bu default it is in debug

My problem was xdebug was in default debug mode, if you want a trace of functions you have to set xdebug.mode = trace in your config.
